# Show that a polynomial has at least 1 real root

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have the polynomial $P(x)=x^{2}+2013x+1$ and a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now I have to show that the polynomial $P(P(...P(x)...)$ $(n$ times$)$ has at least one real root. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the quadratic equation 
$$P(x)=x$$
has some real root $x_-<0$.

For every $n\ge 1$, denote the $n$-th iteration of $P$ by $P^{\circ n}$. Then 
$$P^{\circ n}(x_-)=x_-<0\quad\text{and}\quad P^{\circ n}(+\infty)=+\infty,$$
so there exists $x_n\in(x_-,+\infty)$, such that $P^{\circ n}(x_n)=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, why is $P^{\circ n}(x_{-})= x_-$?

Comment: @EricAuld: Since $P(x_-)=x_-$, $P(P(x_-))=P(x_-)=x_-$, and so on.

Comment: I thought $P(x_-) = 0$.

Comment: @Eric The first line of the answer states that $x_{-}$ is the real root of the quadratic equation $P(x)=x$, i.e., $P(x_{-})=x_{-}$ ...

Comment: Oh, I see. Whoops!

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial has two real zeros, call them $a$ and $b$, where $a<b$ (this we can tell from taking the discriminant). If you can show that $P([a,b])\supset [a, b]$, then you're home free, because then $a$ has a preimage $c_1\in [a,b]$, then $c_1$ has a preimage $c_2\in [a,b]$, then...

Comment: Presumaby $f(x)=P(x)$, no?

Comment: Whoops! Fixed. --